# How do you send POST parameters to a function in PHP using Fat-Free-Framework?

Tags: php, post, url-routing, fat-free-framework

The documentation on the website is a bit lacking (http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine). I want to use the shorthand expression of POST:

```
$f3->route('POST /login','Auth::login');
```

How do you send params into the Auth->login() function above?

This is an alternative way of writing it, but a bit longer:

```
$f3->route('POST /login',
    function($f3) {
        $params = $f3->get('POST');
        $Auth = new Auth;
        $Auth->login($params['username'], $params['password']);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the `Auth::login` should automatically receive the POST data as an argument, then you can't.

All F3 route handlers receive the following arguments:

1. the framework instance
2. the route tokens (if any)

See [here](http://fatfreeframework.com/base#RouteHandler) for an example.

Anyway, if the `Auth->login` function you're referring to is the [one included in the framework](http://fatfreeframework.com/auth#Authenticating), then it couldn't work in any manner since the `login()` function **is not a route handler**. It simply returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. A route handler has to do a little bit more than that: for example, to reroute the user on success or to display the login form again on error.

Comment: Yep, finally figured out all route handlers receive the f3 instance and route tokens. And then you would access the POST params with the f3 instance within the Auth function (for this example).

Comment: The example on their [site](http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine) shows `'WebPage->display'` which maps to `function display()`. It would be more clear to a beginner to show that it is actually `function display($f3, $params)`. I didn't know both were "just passed."

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$f3->route('POST /login',
function($f3,$params) {
    $Auth = new Auth;
    $Auth->login($params['username'], $params['password']);
}
);
```